# Where can I implement polymorphism?

Tags: java

Sorry to ask this silly question, I'm new to Java.
I have a super class called Sales Manager, and its subclass are ItemEntry, SupplierEntry, PurchaseRequisition and so on. Can anyone suggest me where to implement the overloading and overriding concept? I mean ya although they are inherited, but Sales Manager and ItemEntry are completely different things isn't?

Unlike the superclass car, subclass Ford, Volkswagen, this only make sense.

Appreciate for you help.

Comment: It doesn't seem to logically follow that an item or supplier entry inherits from a sales manager.  You may want to rethink your design here.

Comment: "although they are inherited, but Sales Manager and ItemEntry are completely different things isn't?" - yes they are (completely different).

Comment: Extending a class is "is-a" relationship and ItemEntry, SupplierEntry, PurchaseRequisition at least to me don't sound well in something like "ItemEntry is a SalesManager". Read more on polymorphism to understand where and how to use it, what are the benefits, why is composition preferred nowadays and how to declare common behaviour for non related classes using interfaces, read more and try to understand, don't just jump into learning stuff from the middle.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, as Tim said, your model might be better suited using something else than PolyMorphism.

Best to think of PolyMorphism where you want to *extend* something to be clearer, or more defined.   I prefer the Animals Example..

```
Dog -> Pet -> Mammal -> Animal -> Genus -> etc....
```

This allows extending objects to add additional and specific members (properties/methods) that can be shared across that classification.

Where you may have something that may be used across Objects, that is not specific, or always present, to an object, you would use **Interfaces**.  These allow you to add extra methods (that the user must define when used) that the object implements.

For example...

Not all birds can be pets, so in the previous setup we may choose to use an *interface* in place of `Pet`.

```
Dog (Implements Pet) -> Mammal -> Animal -> ...
```

So then we could use the same *interface* on anything else we polymorph, such as a bird.

```
Parrot (Implements Pet) -> Bird -> Animal -> ...
```

It's a bit to get your head around at first, so I would suggest playing with some simple examples and go from there.

So for your *Sales Manager* example, you might use the following setup as they are related...

Sales Manager -> Manager -> Employee -> Person

Your *ItemEntry, SupplierEntry, PurchaseRequisition* you could use as properties or *SalesManager*.

Hope that helps